# TFS 2010 : how to retrieve a deleted file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

How can I retrieve a deleted file in TFS 2010?

I had a Visual Studio 2010 project checked into TFS. I deleted a file locally (`.edmx`). Now, I want to retrieve that file.

Comment: Does updating your edmx file from database not work?

Comment: @caglar_gonul, yes it would but I had some customizations in that .edmx that will not be gotten back if I just update from the database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the file still exists in TFS, then you locate the file and do `Get Latest`.  This will bring the file back to your local machine.

**EDIT**

Maybe this link will help you:

[How to retrieve a deleted file in TFS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/d0b3a884-46a8-4a1a-b597-5a5e53b87923)

Comment: the file doesn't exist in TFS anymore even though I did not check in my changes, strange.

Comment: correction : I did find the file in TFS and it was marked for deletion, I simply did an "Undo Changes" , I was looking at the wrong stuff before.